# Gráfico Chart JS - Inserir Label no Centro do Doughnut Charts

Tags: chartjs

Tenho um gráfico do tipo Doughnut Charts - http://www.chartjs.org/ - e gostaria que o Label estivesse presente no centro do gráfico.

Saberiam se isto é possível?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mayankcpdixit/6xV78/, da uma olhada veja se é isso que precisa,

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada nele outro dia, mas tem um monte de código JS ali e não consegui compreender em qual momento é gerado o label no centro.

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto Conseguiu a resposta para sua pergunta já ?

Comment: Eu sei que já se passaram 7 anos, mas não encontrei uma solução dessa por aqui (pelo menos com as palavras chaves que coloquei no Google para achar essa postagem)... Então, fiz uns testes e cheguei nessa solução simples:
https://codepen.io/mayconvs/pen/eYjgVgv